# Git ignore changes, pull latest, come back later

Tags: git, git-pull

I need to store all my old changes to a branch in git and merge them tomorrow. Today, I need to pull the latest changes and help someone else test code without adding my untested work.

It looks like in order to make my changes into a new local branch, I need to do a pull and merge their huge code changes with mine. I don't have time for that.

How do I pull all the latest code and do the merges later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new branch and commit:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git commit -a
```

Then you can go to the original branch and update it:

```
git checkout original_branch
git pull
```

Later, you can merge the changes from new_branch into original_branch:

```
git checkout original_branch
git merge new_branch
```

Also, if you quickly want to put aside your current changes, you can stash them. Check out `git help stash` for details.